# Laravel Password Reset issue when using Username instead of Email

Tags: php, laravel, passwords, reset-password

Has anyone successfully implemented a custom Reset Password using `Username` instead of `Email`?

I've been tracing the source code as to how Laravel does the resetting of password but I don't see where it's using the `email` field to query to the `password_resets` table on the `Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBroker.php`

I'm currently `NOT` sending any `Password Reset Request through the mail`, just generating a token and saving it to the `password_resets` table and passing the token to the `password reset form`

`I'm NOT sending any reset link to an email`

I'm currently having this error when I'm submitting the Reset Password Form

`the issue is WHEN RESETTING the password, Laravel is using the email column to query the password_resets table instead of username column. I can't seem to find where it's triggering this query`

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'email' in 'where clause'
SELECT * FROM `password_resets` WHERE `email` IS NULL limit 1
```

My `password_resets table` has `username` and `token` fields.

My `ResetPasswordController.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admins\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rules;

class ResetPasswordController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Reset Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller is responsible for handling password reset requests
    | and uses a simple trait to include this behavior. You're free to
    | explore this trait and override any methods you wish to tweak.
    |
    */

    use ResetsPasswords;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after resetting their password.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Display the password reset view for the given token.
     *
     * If no token is present, display the link request form.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory|\Illuminate\View\View
     */
    public function showResetPasswordForm(Request $request)
    {
        $token = $request->route()->parameter('token');

        return view('admins.auth.passwords.reset')->with(
            ['token' => $token, 'username' => $request->username]
        );
    }

    /**
     * Reset the given user's password.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function resetPassword(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate($this->rules(), $this->validationErrorMessages());

        $response = $this->broker()->reset(
            $this->credentials($request),
            function ($user, $password) {
                $this->resetPassword($user, $password);
            }
        );

        return $response == Password::PASSWORD_RESET
                    ? $this->sendResetResponse($request, $response)
                    : $this->sendResetFailedResponse($request, $response);
    }

    /**
     * Get the password reset validation rules.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function rules()
    {
        return [
            'token' => 'required',
            'username' => 'required|min:2',
            'password' => ['required', 'confirmed', Rules\Password::defaults()],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the password reset credentials from the request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    protected function credentials(Request $request)
    {
        return $request->only(
            'username',
            'password',
            'password_confirmation',
            'token'
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get the response for a failed password reset.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  string  $response
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse|\Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    protected function sendResetFailedResponse(Request $request, $response)
    {
        if ($request->wantsJson()) {
            throw ValidationException::withMessages([
                'username' => [trans($response)],
            ]);
        }

        return redirect()->back()
                    ->withInput($request->only('username'))
                    ->withErrors(['username' => trans($response)]);
    }

    /**
     * Get the broker to be used during password reset.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\PasswordBroker
     */
    public function broker()
    {
        return Password::broker('admins');
    }

    /**
     * Get the guard to be used during password reset.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard
     */
    protected function guard()
    {
        return Auth::guard('web-admins');
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you sending your password reset request via email ?

Comment: @xenooooo no I don't, I'm bypassing the request via email cause I'm using `username`, so I'm NOT sending any password request through a mail

it works normally when I'm using the `email` field but I'm not going through the email itself. just directly generating a token and saving that token in the `password_resets` table and passing it to the password reset form.

but then they don't want to use email, but username instead directly.

Comment: @xenooooo I don't think that would matter cause the problem is when triggering the reset password via `PasswordBroker.php`, I want to know where it's querying it, so I can change the `email` to `username`

Comment: @xenooooo I could just manually code the logic, but it would be better to use the `PasswordBroker.php`

Comment: Well `PasswordBroker.php` is dependent to the email.

Comment: I gave up, `email` column is hard coded to be used. I just manually code everything. I just followed how they're doing all the security checks

Answer (score -1):

In **ForgotPasswordController** You should have 2 methods like:

```
protected function credentials(Request $request)
    {
        return $request->only(
            'username', 'password', 'password_confirmation', 'token'
        );
    }

    protected function rules()
    {
        return [
            'token' => 'required',
            'username' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:8',
        ];
    }
```

You need to change keys as per your request parameters, Hope this is going to help you.

Comment: This is a `send reset link email`, I'm NOT sending any email cause I'm not using it. I only have `username` and `password` on my `admins`

Comment: you might want to read the original post again bro

Comment: I'm not using the auth.passwords.email at all, cause I'm just generating the token and saving it to the `password_resets` table and passing that token to the auth.passwords.reset form.

Comment: When you are generating token for password_reset you need to mention key for which you need to try to reset password just like sendResetLinkEmail function above. if yo are not sending any emails you need to make hash using key you are going to pass to credentials and validation for ForgotPasswordController you should have 2 methods be like below code: if you have your request limited to input you can replace both keys accordingly. Hope this will helps you.

Comment: protected function credentials(Request $request)
    {
        return $request->only(
            'username', 'password', 'password_confirmation', 'token'
        );
    }

    protected function rules()
    {
        return [
            'token' => 'required',
            'username' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:8',
        ];
    }

Comment: If you are not using Laravel Auth then you can reset directly by User instance.

$user = user::where('username', 'xyz')->firstOrfail();
$user->password = bcrypt($requst->password);
$user->save();

return redirect('login')->with("message","Password updated successfully.");

Comment: yeah I know, but I don't want to do that, I want to use the `Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBroker.php`, I'm utilizing the `Auth/PasswordResetContoller.php`

Comment: I did updated my answer for controller and that should work by placing 2 functions within your controller if you want using Laravel native auth functionality.

Comment: that doesn't make sense cause `ForgotPasswordController.php` is being used to send the email for `Requesting Password Reset` BUT I'm not sending any emails at all. I think you don't understand my original post.

Comment: the Controller handling the Password Resets is `PasswordResetController.php` which I already have configured properly on my original post above.

Comment: you might want to check my PasswordResetController.php `credentials` and `rules` method, they correct and working fine.

the issue is WHEN RESETTING the password, Laravel is using `email` to query the `password_resets` table instead of `username`. I can't seem to find where it's triggering this query.

Comment: Bro, as I said above on my original post, I'm not sending any emails, I'm generating tokens and saving it to the `password_resets table` and passing to the reset password form, IT ALREADY WORKS NORMALLY. what I want is not to use `email` field BUT `username` field.

Comment: try to read my original post carefully again.

Comment: the problem is when Laravel is querying the `password_resets` table, it's using `email` instead of `username` column. that's the issue.

Comment: Brother  credentials() & resetPassword() are 2 function responsible for all of reset password functionality at the you will see data saved ad User model by setting up password. You can review file from path 

\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords.php

Comment: I'm assuming you're using `Breeze` for this, it might have a different implementation.

Cause you see, `Password Reset` uses a hardcoded field name `email` in `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\DatabaseTokenRepository.php`. check this file and you'll see as to why `username` won't work.

you'll see `email` fields everywhere, this is what the Password Reset uses.